# Unity Sort list by object property with nulls?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, unity-game-engine

I have a List of items that contain a WeaponData object -- however it could be null (if it's equipment and not a weapon)

I'm trying to sort the list based on WeaponData.Type, and have the nulls be at the bottom.

```
items.Sort((p1,p2)=>{
    if(p2.WeaponData == null) return -1;
    else if(p1.WeaponData == null) return 1;
    return p2.WeaponData.Type.CompareTo(p1.WeaponData.Type);
});
```

This technically should work, as it should drop nulls to the bottom and then evaluate the weapon type, but it throws the following error:

> ArgumentException: Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results.

How can I make this properly sort and throw nulls at the bottom? Thanks!

Comment: Well, what do you think happens when you pass in the same object for both `p1` and `p2` into the lambda? It definitely won't return 0 if its `WeaponData` is `null` - which it should

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, turns out I needed a setup for when the values are equal:

```
items.Sort((p1,p2)=>{
    if(p1.WeaponData == p2.WeaponData) return 0;
    else if(p2.WeaponData == null) return -1;
    else if(p1.WeaponData == null) return 1;
    else return p2.WeaponData.Type.CompareTo(p1.WeaponData.Type);
});
```